# Cin.get() issue with C++

Tags: c++

I still don't know how this works with Visual Studio.

Supposedly it keeps my console open, but it doesn't. It still flashes and closes.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "You typed 1.";
    }   
    else
        cout << "That's not 1.";

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll have the `ENTER` character in your input stream which is immediately consumed by `cin.get();`.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. So how would I fix that? ^

Comment: Try `cin.get()` *twice*.

Comment: do `cin.ignore()` before `cin.get()`

Comment: Someone asked this like.. yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new here. I'll search next time.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed out in the comments the problem is that the input buffer contains the symbol of the Enter key that is read by cin.get();
You can use either the following sequence

```
char c;

cin >> c;
```

Or before cin.get() you should call cin.ignore. For example

```
cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
cin.get();
```

In the last case you must include header `<limits>`